# flutter web loading first page size

Tags: lazy-loading, flutter-web

I am programming a large web site.
My main problem is the volume of the web at the end of the work
When the user enters the website address, are all the designed web pages loaded or only the first page is loaded and other pages are loaded according to the user's request?
Because in other programming languages, the entire website is not loaded, but this happens in web applications.

Comment: The other pages/screens/components that are dependent on user's action don't load unless user clicks a button which does it. For example, if user is on the login page, the home page isn't loaded unless user clicks a button which opens up the home page.

Comment: thanks but i make a sample app with 5 different pages all page loads together ! how can stop loading all pages together?

Comment: If that's the case with your code then you must be doing something wrong and I or any other user here can't help you in your code without your code.

Comment: my sample code is Hello World! but when you click on + it navigate you to new page with same as first page and when you click on + floating button navigate to third page and its continue for 5 page all pages navigate with:           Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => a1(
                  title: '',
                ),
              )),     (Uploaded app here):  aqaq.gigfa.com